# GHCI 7.8.3 does not support utf8 characters

Tags: haskell, utf-8, ghc, ghci

I've read in the utf8-string package that ghc should support utf8 by default. I've even seen somewhere being written that now my default codepage is used.

Despite all that, a simple code does not execute.

```
writeFile "asd.txt" "ćlččć"
```

returns

```
*** Exception: filenames.txt: commitBuffer: invalid argument (invalid character)
```

How do I get this code to execute?

Comment: Could I get some clarification on the downvotes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you should set the encoding of the handle you're actually writing to. I don't know for sure, since I can't reproduce your problem, but something like this may do:

```
withFile "asd.txt" WriteMode $ \h -> do
    hSetEncoding h utf8
    hPutStr h "ćlččć"
```

Comment: Yeah, that does it. You are only missing `>>` there

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic Whoops, added a `do`.

Comment: Note that the windows console will give garbled output if you just use hSetEncoding utf8 unless it's using the utf8 codepage. To solve it just use the fact that `(\e -> mkTextEncoding (show e ++ "//TRANSLIT")) :: TextEncoding -> IO TextEncoding` when passed a valid `TextEncoding` returns essentially the same encoding but without the exception-throwing behaviour when undefined characters are used.